# How do you raise a python exception and include additional data for Sentry?

Tags: python, django, exception, sentry

Sentry can detect additional data associated with an exception such as:

[image]

How do you raise such an exception from Python (it's a Django app) with your own `additional data` fields?.

Comment: `raise` takes any class or instance.  Can you be clearer about what you're asking?

Comment: What additional data do you want to add?

Comment: offtopic - but where is your screenshot from? why don't i have such pretty exceptions in django? - edit: sorry, it is sentry.

Comment: @user1688936: It's the whole point of the question, I think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I log exceptions using the `logging` library so after debugging the code a bit, I noticed the `extra` parameter:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('my_app_name')

def do_something():

    try:
        #do some stuff here that might break

    except Exception, e:
        logger.error(e, exc_info=1, extra={'extra-data': 'blah', })
```

Passing exc_info=1 is the same as calling `logger.exception`. However, `exception()` does not accept kwargs, which are required for using the `extra` parameter.

These values will show up in the 'Additional Data' section of the Sentry Error dashboard.

Comment: This is it.  If you're using Raven client you can: ["pass it as data within your extra clause"](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/logging.html) `e.g.: logger.error('There was some crazy error', exc_info=True, extra={'data': {'username': request.user.username}})`

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. `logger.error(...)` won't re-raise the exception, so it will just swallow it and continue. How would you actually raise an exception with additional data?

Answer (score 4):

[wes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414701/220652) didn't help me because I want to actually **raise** an exception, **not only log** it.

Here's what I did (`client` is the Raven Sentry client):

```py
client.extra_context({'foo': 'bar'})
raise RuntimeError('Whoops, something went wrong!')
```

Comment: if this exception gets handled (= doesnt crash the application), every follow-up exception will have the same context, even if not relevant

Answer (score 2):

You might try one of these two approaches:

```
>>> # Raise the exception with the data you want.
>>> raise Exception('extra information')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception('extra information')
Exception: extra information
>>> # Catch an exception and add extra arguments.
>>> try:
    raise Exception()
except Exception as error:
    error.args += ('extra information',)
    raise

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 2, in <module>
    raise Exception()
Exception: extra information
>>>
```

You can add as many additional data fields as you want by adding more arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sentry handler](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/master/raven/handlers/logbook.py) adds that info in your screenshot when capturing the message for an exception, and takes that information from the *traceback*, not the exception itself.

You can add extra fields by passing extra keyword arguments to `.capture()`; the [Django client](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/master/raven/contrib/django/client.py) does so for you if you pass in the `request` object, for example.

Currently, no other data is taken from exceptions. You'd have to expand the exception handling yourself to add such a facility.

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers served my exact use case well (which was to add additional context from the django `Request` object into the sentry data). What ended up working very well for that after some digging was overriding the client using the [`SENTRY_CLIENT` setting](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/#additional-settings).

Here's a complete simple use case:

```
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat import DjangoClient

class CustomSentryClient(DjangoClient):

    def get_data_from_request(self, request):
        result = super(EToolsSentryClient, self).get_data_from_request(request)
        if getattr(request, 'custom_field', None):
            if 'extra' not in result:
                result['extra'] = {}
            result['extra']['custom_field'] = request.custom_field
        return result
```

and then in `settings.py` you would just add

```
SENTRY_CLIENT = 'myapp.CustomSentryClient'
```